# Is there any function in musl like "backtrace" in glibc

Tags: pthreads, glibc, alpine-linux, musl

I'm trying to translate my code from centos to Alpine-docker , but Alpine really lack of some  functions， like  "backtrace"  "pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np"  etc.. How could I use them in Alpine or are there any functions instead?

Answer (score 0):

musl does not provide `backtrace`.

You may use an external [`libexecinfo`](https://github.com/ronchaine/libexecinfo) library to provide it.
It was specifically exactly for the purpose of porting programs requiring glibc backtrace facility.